# How to make objects not touch in Python

Tags: python, graphics

So, I'm making a program and the program makes 250 dots in random colors and prints them on a window. But they cannot touch each other.

Here is my code

```
from graphics import *
from random import *
import math

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Dots", 1100, 650)
    dots = []
    points = []
    for x in range(0,250):
         drawCircle(win, dots, points)
    checkOverLap(dots, points)
    drawAllCircles(win, dots)

def drawCircle(win, array, points):
    p1 = randint(15,1085)
    p2 = randint(15,635)
    dot = Circle(Point(p1, p2), 15)
    r = lambda: randint(0,255)
    dot.setFill('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
    array.append(dot)
    points.append(Point(p1, p2))


def checkOverLap(array, points):
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, 250):
         for y in range(0, 250):
             if x != y:
                if math.hypot(points[y].getX() - points[x].getX(), points[y].getY() - points[x].getY()) < 30:
                    dist = math.hypot(points[y].getX() - points[x].getX(), points[y].getY() - points[x].getY())
                    newCircle = Circle(Point(points[x].getX() + (abs(dist - 31)), points[x].getY() + (abs(dist - 31))), 15)
                    r = lambda: randint(0,255)
                    newCircle.setFill('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
                    array[x] = newCircle


def drawAllCircles(win, array):
    for x in range(0, 250):
        array[x].draw(win)



main()
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Does check overlap work? Are all circles uniform in radii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from graphics import *
from random import *
import math

def main():
  win = GraphWin("Dots", 1100, 650)
  dots = []
  for x in xrange(250):
    #Create a random circle
    circle = getdrawCircle(15, 635, 15, 1085, 15, 15)
    #Repeat while overlap with other circles
    while checkOverLap(circle, dots):
      #Create a new random circle
      circle = getdrawCircle(15, 635, 15, 1085, 15, 15)
    #The new circle isn't overlap, then append to list dots
    dots.append(circle)
  drawAllCircles(win, dots)

def getdrawCircle(min_height, max_height, min_width, max_width, min_radius, max_radius):
  x = randint(min_height, max_height)
  y = randint(min_width, max_width)
  dot = Circle(Point(y, x), randint(min_radius, max_radius))
  r = lambda: randint(0,255)
  dot.setFill('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
  return dot

#If circle overlap with circles in array then return True
def checkOverLap(circle, array):
  for circle_cmp in array:
    dist = math.hypot(circle.getCenter().getX() - circle_cmp.getCenter().getX(), 
                      circle.getCenter().getY() - circle_cmp.getCenter().getY())
    if dist < circle.getRadius() + circle_cmp.getRadius():
      return True
  return False

def drawAllCircles(win, array):
  for x in range(0, 250):
    array[x].draw(win)

main()
```

Comment: @user3344862 you may changed to `circle = getdrawCircle(15, 635, 15, 1085, 10, 25)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a windows computer, so I will give you my best answer.

Try picking the random number for the coordinates of the circle, and loop through the already drawn circles and see if a circle drawn at those coordinates would touch anything else. Using a `while` loop, you can keep picking random coordinates until they do not touch anything else:

```
circles = list_of_circles_drawn
radius = radius_of_circles;
x = random.randint(1, 1000)
y = random.randint(1, 1000)
while any([math.sqrt(math.pow(math.fabs(x-c.x), 2)+math.pow(math.fabs(y-c.y), 2)) < radius for c in circles]):
    x = random.randint(1, 1000)
    y = random.randint(1, 1000)
```